# Should put the MacOS bomb dialog on the maintenance page of SF

Tags: discussion

For a little of retro effect.  Sure had to deal with that plenty of times back in the day...

[MacOS Bomb http://www.sqeq.com/image/macos_bomb.jpg](http://www.sqeq.com/image/macos_bomb.jpg)

Comment: Or a BSOD if the browser says it's on a Windows computer.

Comment: That one's already there.  Same with an X11 dump

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a good fit for a server based site, is it? Macs aren't exactly known for "server-ness"..

Comment: Huge part of IT is desktop support.  Ever run a Mac lab at a university in the early-mid 90's?  ugh...

Comment: But I'll concede and accept.